# Use Web.Config to redirect a directory to a subdomain

Tags: iis, redirect, web-config

I have a subdirectory (`http://example.com/forum`) I want to 301-redirect to a new subdomain at `htttp://forum.exampple.com`. How can I set up a redirect using Web.config and IIS rewrite to send all requests to `http://example.com/forum/*` to `htttp://forum.exampple.com`? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

By converting the rule provided by ssri, the rule should look like this in the web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="your name here" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^forum/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://forum.exampple.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Put it between the system.webServer tags.

Comment: This works, but for some reason it passes the querystring to the subdomain - any way I can stop it from doing this?

Comment: @MarathonStudios
I believe removing the {R:1} will remove the relative path. 
So change:

<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://forum.exampple.com/{R:1}" />

to

<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://forum.exampple.com/" />

Answer (score 0):

To get ride of the querystring being passed to the subdomain can you try like this

RewriteRule ^/forum/(.*)/? http://forum.exampple.com/$1 [R=301,L]

In the rewrite rule if you end with $ it will take the entire url (including the query), so try replacing the $ with /? to get the truncated request without query.

If you are sure your new url doesn't need any querystring you can change it to

RewriteRule ^/forum/(.*)/? http://forum.exampple.com/$1/? [R=301,L]

Comment: @MarathonStudios: Copy the rule provided by ssri and paste it into the "Import Rules" feature in IIS URL rewrite module to get the correct XML formatting.

Comment: @nctml: I have not learnt about using XML for redirects. Can you provide me some links for me to learn.