# Creating SubDomain for an account on registration with iis7 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I am digging from 3 days all over the Stackoverflow and google. I am not getting any exact steps, how to accomplish it... I read all these questions on stackoverflow, many person asked this same question and not got exact Steps to do this Task.

[subdomain rewriting in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322151/subdomain-rewriting-in-asp-net#)

https://serverfault.com/questions/58050/generating-content-based-on-subdomain

[Creating subdomains on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190309/creating-subdomains-on-the-fly)

[ASP.NET virtual subdomain via Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126438/asp-net-virtual-subdomain-via-rewrite?rq=1)

[How to add a subdomain to an asp.net website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943581/how-to-add-a-subdomain-to-an-asp-net-website?lq=1)

[How to allow users to create their own subdomains on my MVC website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994128/how-to-allow-users-to-create-their-own-subdomains-on-my-mvc-website?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[web.config rule for sub-directory to sub-domain redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044880/web-config-rule-for-sub-directory-to-sub-domain-redirection)

[Use Web.Config to redirect a directory to a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202045/use-web-config-to-redirect-a-directory-to-a-subdomain)

[URL Rewrite for subdomains in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661605/url-rewrite-for-subdomains-in-asp-net?rq=1)

**Now this is i am trying to do: When user register on my website, that time create a subdomain with user name like this**

< username >.domain.com like abc.domain.com, xyz.domain.com

and It must points to domain.com/Users/< username >/index.asp

This is a good example http://ytmnd.com/

**I am using Windows hosting with IIS7 and i am using asp.net.**

I set the Wildcard entry in DNS, when user hit < anyname >.domain.com then it pointing to default Plesk webpage of server;

I dnt have any clue it suppose to work like that or it should point to my main domain.com

Please Provide me steps to complete this task
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you use the answer provided in your own link?

[How to allow users to create their own subdomains on my MVC website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994128/how-to-allow-users-to-create-their-own-subdomains-on-my-mvc-website?answertab=votes#tab-top)

> The bind DNS server and Microsoft DNS server both allow to setup a wildcard entry that match any nonexisting entry in the domain:
>
> *.example.com.   3600 IN  CNAME host1.example.com.
> Then you setup an URL rewrite rule in the IIS that turns the URL of the form http://subdomain.yourdomain.com/ into, say, http://yourdomain.com/?root=subdomain
>
> This will allow you to manage these cloned sites using a database.
>
> The only drawback is that DNS system does not allow you to setup a wildcard entry of the form www.*.yourdomain.tld

Comment: Thank you for reply, i try it but got stuck after second step.. it says "then you setup an URL rewrite rule in the IIS that turns the URL of the form ....... "  as i am using shared hosting from a hosting company, i do not have direct access to IIS. so how to achieve that step?

Comment: davids, i got some improvement, now when i enter <anything>.mydomain.com then it direct it to mydomain.com. now do not have next clue what to do, so it will direct to user folder, eg. user1.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/users/user1/index.aspx